# How time consuming is it to port a Webforms site to MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

How time consuming is it to move a website built using Webforms to one built using MVC?

I have an existing website built using asp.net webforms, but it is a little annoying. I want to use lots of javascript and ajax, but webforms makes this a little difficult. It tries to do too much for me, and thus makes it difficult to work with when I want to do things it doesn't expect.

As such, I've taken to only using the `Page_Load` event, and totally ignoring all the postback stuff - when I need to deal with submitting forms, I handle it manually from the `Page_Load` event with `Request.Form["ElementName"]`, but most of the time I use javascript.

I've heard that asp.net MVC is much nicer to work with, so I'm thinking of porting my site over to this. Given that I am writing `runat="server"` only on standard HTML elements that I need to fill with data with `.innerHTML =`, how long will it take me to move over to MVC? Or is it a totally stupid idea to attempt this move?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, as you've probably guessed, it's such a broad ranging question that it would be almost impossible to give advice on your individual scenario without seeing the scale of the existing codebase. However, there are many mitigating factors that you may want to think of regarding moving functionality across piecemeal, such as:

- can I break down the existing functionality into discreet segments
- does the exisiting site still require all current features
- are there new features that I could introduce purely in mvc
- do i need to extend the object model - EF code-first may give huge advantage via mvcscaffolding

the beauty with asp.net is that you can mix-match webforms and mvc together, thus you can chip away at functionality as required. Of course, there are so many resources on mvc on the web now, it'll be easy to get going quickly, so i'm sure you'll make good progress.

I think you'll really enjoy mvc - it's a **no going back experience**.

**[edit]** - there are a few interesting resources on the web that discuss the mix of webforms and mvc. however, the definitive one for me has to be scott hanselmans from a wee while back. still relevent in mvc3 as it was then:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

also:

http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/general/mixing-asp-net-mvc-and-webforms

Comment: +1 mix and match - you can convert areas at a time and phase webforms out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try running MVC and webforms together. It's probably better this way too as I can work out the extra stuff possible with MVC slowly.

Comment: Yes +1, but at the same time maybe elaborate on the combined model a little bit.

Comment: henk -good point. will update answer with pointers to the hanselman piece

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, impossible to tell here.

Long answer, it depends...

It depends on how many sites you have to rewrite, complexity of the site and your architecture.

If all your logic is in the code behind files you will have a long walk. 
If your architecture separates responsibility with use of services and abstraction, a lot easier.

If I should walk that walk, I would look into porting the code bit by bit. I've done this with JSF and Spring MVC, and it looks like this is doable with .Net too.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/11/running-asp-net-webforms-and-asp-net-mvc-side-by-side.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Most of the logic is in separate files from the codebehind. I've tried to make it so that the codebehind is only rendering data to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to improve your code and your skills is never a stupid move!

It is possible to use them both within the same application. It isn't necessarily advisable, but if you set an MVC project up, you can tell it to ignore page requests that map to your webform pages.

You can then start moving over functionality as you need it.

If there is likely to be functionality you need to be available across MVC and webform pages, then this is going to get complicated and you are probably best moving to MVC in one go.

Personally, what ever you do, start small and straightforward and if you can bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be a rewrite, not a port. MVC sites are built very differently from WebForms sites.

MVC is not based on the ASP.NET request lifecycle. There is no codebehind; business logic gets called from Controller classes; data is encapsulated in Models which are then passed to Views. It's a totally different beast from ASP.NET.

And be warned: once you've made the switch to MVC, you'll never go back to the old world of ASP.NET! :-)

Good luck!

Comment: `MVC is not based on the ASP.NET request lifecycle`. Not true since MVC is built upon ASP.NET.

Comment: In an MVC site there are no Page events such as Page Init, Page Load, etc.

Comment: What have the with the `ASP.NET` request life cycle to do? You are maybe referring to the webforms Page lifecycle?